# CMS которая создает динамические ссылки на статические страницы

Tags: php, cms

Добрый день!
Мне нужно, чтобы CMS генерировал разные ссылки на одну и ту же страницу.
Время существования ссылки на страницу безгранично.

CMS может быть разной - или это для блогов или это для создания сайта. Ресурс будет несложным - всего каких-то простых 5 страниц.

Comment: т.е. вы хотите N ссылок на один и тот же материал? )

Comment: да. необходимо эти ссылки с моего ресурса кодировать на сайтах по укорочению ссылок, чтобы было множество коротких ссылок и их нельзя было пофиксить программно

Comment: бред.......

Comment: согласен, бред... Конечно можно придумать кокой нить скриптик на php, но не вижу практических применений этого (может СЕО таким образом поднять хотите?). И не слышал чтобы cms-ки этим занимались

Answer (score 1):

Не одна CMS не поддерживает такой функционал(ибо не зачем). Однако Если вам это все же нужно то реализуется это следующим образом:
 1. Для каждой страницы создается свой id.
 2. Этот id обязательно должен быть get параметром во всех ссылках на страницу.
 3. К сслыке вида www.yoursite/?id=234 добавляете "соль" и получаете что-то вроде www.yoursite/?id=234&qrtyed и т.д